# Conditional means based on other columns in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data:

```
structure(list(political_spectrum = c(5L, 15L, 12L, 30L, 100L, 
0L, 27L, 52L, 38L, 64L, 0L, 0L, 76L, 50L, 16L, 16L, 0L, 23L, 
0L, 25L, 68L, 50L, 4L, 0L, 50L), politics_today = c("Independent", 
"Strong Democrat", "Weak Democrat", "Weak Democrat", "Weak Republican", 
"Strong Democrat", "Weak Democrat", "Weak Democrat", "Independent", 
"Weak Democrat", "Strong Democrat", "Independent", "Weak Republican", 
"Weak Democrat", "Weak Democrat", "Strong Democrat", "Strong Democrat", 
"Strong Democrat", "Strong Democrat", "Strong Democrat", "Independent", 
"Independent", "Strong Democrat", "Strong Democrat", "Independent"
), stranger_things_universe_mc = c("The Demagorgon", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "The Stranger Land", "The Demagorgon", 
"The Upside Down", "", "", "", "", "", "The Upside Down", "The Shadowland", 
"", "", "", "", "", "The Shadowland"), stranger_things_universe_answer = c("The Upside Down", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "The Upside Down", "The Upside Down", 
"The Upside Down", "", "", "", "", "", "The Upside Down", "The Upside Down", 
"", "", "", "", "", "The Upside Down"), stranger_things_universe_confidence = c(32L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 67L, 94L, 89L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 51L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L), stranger_things_universe_importance = c("Don't care at all", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Care somewhat strongly", "Care a little", 
"Care somewhat strongly", "", "", "", "", "", "Care somewhat", 
"Don't care at all", "", "", "", "", "", "Don't care at all"), 
    tupac_mc = c("", "Biggie Smalls", "", "", "", "", "", "Biggie Smalls", 
    "Biggie Smalls", "", "", "Biggie Smalls", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "Biggie Smalls", "", "", "Ice Cube", "", "", ""), 
    tupac_answer = c("", "Biggie Smalls", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "Biggie Smalls", "Biggie Smalls", "", "", "Biggie Smalls", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "Biggie Smalls", "", "", "Biggie Smalls", 
    "", "", ""), tupac_confidence = c(NA, 70L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 71L, 76L, NA, NA, 100L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100L, 
    NA, NA, 32L, NA, NA, NA), tupac_importance = c("", "Don't care at all", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "Care somewhat", "Don't care at all", 
    "", "", "Care strongly", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Care a little", 
    "", "", "Don't care at all", "", "", ""), uber_ceo_mc = c("John Zimmer", 
    "", "", "", "", "Travis Kalanick", "", "", "", "Travis Kalanick", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "John Zimmer", "Travis Kalanick", 
    "Travis Kalanick", "", "", "", "", ""), uber_ceo_answer = c("Travis Kalanick", 
    "", "", "", "", "Travis Kalanick", "", "", "", "Travis Kalanick", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Travis Kalanick", "Travis Kalanick", 
    "Travis Kalanick", "", "", "", "", ""), uber_ceo_confidence = c(0L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 94L, NA, NA, NA, 69L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5L, 13L, 17L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), uber_ceo_importance = c("Don't care at all", 
    "", "", "", "", "Care strongly", "", "", "", "Care somewhat", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Don't care at all", "Don't care at all", 
    "Care somewhat", "", "", "", "", ""), black_panther_mc = c("", 
    "T'Chaka", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "T'Chaka", "", ""), black_panther_answer = c("", 
    "T'Challa", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "T'Challa", "", ""), black_panther_confidence = c(NA, 
    63L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 34L, NA, NA), black_panther_importance = c("", 
    "Don't care at all", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Care a little", 
    "", ""), the_office_mc = c("The Mindy Project", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "The Office", "", 
    "", "The Mindy Project", "", "", "", "", "The Office", "", 
    ""), the_office_answer = c("The Office", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "The Office", "", "", 
    "The Office", "", "", "", "", "The Office", "", ""), the_office_confidence = c(43L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 
    NA, 11L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100L, NA, NA), the_office_importance = c("Don't care at all", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Don't care at all", 
    "", "", "Care a little", "", "", "", "", "Care a little", 
    "", ""), arms_manufacturing_company_mc = c("J. Brockton & Sons", 
    "", "", "O.F. Mossberg & Sons", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "J. Brockton & Sons", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "J. Brockton & Sons"), arms_manufacturing_company_answer = c("J. Brockton & Sons", 
    "", "", "J. Brockton & Sons", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "J. Brockton & Sons", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "J. Brockton & Sons"), arms_manufacturing_company_confidence = c(91L, 
    NA, NA, 24L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100L), arms_manufacturing_company_importance = c("Don't care at all", 
    "", "", "Don't care at all", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "Don't care at all", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "Don't care at all")), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
test %>%
  gather(name, value, -c('political_spectrum', 'politics_today')) %>%
  filter(value != "") %>%
  mutate(question_id = sub("_[^_]+$", "", name)) %>%
  mutate(confidence = grepl("_confidence", name)) %>%
  group_by(politics_today, question_id) %>%
  summarize(mean_confidence = mean(value[confidence == "TRUE"]))
```

in which I get the mean_confidence values for each political affiliation, but only for specific rows in the "value" column.  In order to run the mean only on "confidence" columns, I am trying to do a filter via `mean(value[confidence == "TRUE"])`, but am not sure the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your code to

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  gather(name, value, -c('political_spectrum', 'politics_today')) %>%
  filter(value != "") %>%
  mutate(question_id = sub("_[^_]+$", "", name),
         confidence = grepl("_confidence", name)) %>%
  group_by(politics_today, question_id) %>%
  summarize(mean_confidence = mean(as.numeric(value[confidence])))


#   politics_today  question_id                mean_confidence
#   <chr>           <chr>                                <dbl>
# 1 Independent     arms_manufacturing_company            95.5
# 2 Independent     stranger_things_universe              40.3
# 3 Independent     the_office                            43  
# 4 Independent     tupac                                 69.3
# 5 Independent     uber_ceo                               0  
# 6 Strong Democrat black_panther                         48.5
# 7 Strong Democrat stranger_things_universe              51.7
# 8 Strong Democrat the_office                            55.5
# 9 Strong Democrat tupac                                 85  
#10 Strong Democrat uber_ceo                              32.2
#11 Weak Democrat   arms_manufacturing_company            24  
#12 Weak Democrat   stranger_things_universe              67  
#13 Weak Democrat   the_office                             2  
#14 Weak Democrat   tupac                                 71  
#15 Weak Democrat   uber_ceo                              69  
#16 Weak Republican arms_manufacturing_company            37
```

Since your `value` column has got both numeric and character values, it gets converted to a character column so you need to change the `value` where `confidence == TRUE` to numeric.

Comment: Amazing! This perhaps deserves another question.  But my actual goal is, instead of grouping by politics_today, to have a column called "mean_confidence_democrats" (includes both Weak and Strong Democrats).  Is there a parsimonious way to do this, or would I use the same kind of idea as in your answer? (Will accept your answer in 3 minutes, when it allows me)

Comment: @Parseltongue I think for that you can `separate` the `politics_today` column into a new column (say `party`) which would have value "Democrat" and "Republican" then group on `party` column and `summarise` to take mean value in the same way ?

Comment: @Parseltongue so maybe something like `test %>%
  gather(name, value, -c('political_spectrum', 'politics_today')) %>%
  filter(value != "") %>%
  mutate(question_id = sub("_[^_]+$", "", name),
        confidence = grepl("_confidence", name)) %>%
  separate(politics_today, into = c("party1", "party2")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(party2)) %>%
  group_by(party2, question_id) %>%
  summarize(mean_confidence = mean(as.numeric(value[confidence])))`

Comment: Ah, perfect.  I understand the basic idea now.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Hmm... actually I'm not sure how to separate the columns.  I tried something like this ` separate(politics_today, into = c("Democrats", "Republicans"), sep = "Weak Democrat | Strong Democrat")`, but it's not working.  Any ideas? @ronak shah

Comment: @Parseltongue did you try the code which I showed above? I have filtered the `NA`s as those are "Independent", It gives you mean for all "Democrats" combined and "Republicans".

Comment: Ah, I see what you did now.  Thanks so much for your help!